# Invocation of unresolved module EXPORTMATRIXTOR (in SAS PROC IML)

Tags: r, sas, sas-iml

I copy pasted the code [from this page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/63541/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_r_sect012.htm) on calling R in SAS IML

I got the errors below.  I don't know why ExportmatrixtoR and Submit are giving me problems.  Help?

> 6          proc iml;
>   NOTE: IML Ready
>   7          q = {3.7, 7.1, 2, 4.2, 5.3, 6.4, 8, 5.7, 3.1, 6.1, 4.4, 5.4, 9.5, 11.2};
>   8          RVar = "rq";
>   9          run ExportMatrixToR( q, RVar );
>   ERROR: Invocation of unresolved module EXPORTMATRIXTOR.
>
> statement : RUN at line 9 column 1
>   10
>   11         submit RVar / R;
>             **__**
>             180
>   ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?

Answer (score 3):

If the function and statement are not recognized, then you are running a release prior to SAS/IML 9.22, which was the third maintenance release of SAS 9.2.  You can [find your version of SAS by following follow these instructions](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/08/26/determine-sas-version-at-run-time/). You might also be interested in the article that describes [what versions of R are supported by various releases of SAS](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/09/16/what-versions-of-r-are-supported-by-sas/).

Answer (score 0):

try "call", not "run"

```
call ExportMatrixToR(q, "rq");
```